# Import large sql file django

Tags: mysql, django, import

I have a sql file that has ~ 42,000 `INSERT` statements

I wondered what the best, and quickest way to import this into an existing table?

I am using django and have just installed `South` too

Any suggestions are welcome.

I originally thought - just bypass `models.py` and directly connect through Sequel Pro for mac, but something tells me this won't make south or django happy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally this is done using a transaction. Edit the file having all the INSERTs. Add a line on top and bottom:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
-- all insert statements go here
COMMIT;
```

Now once you login to MySQL from the command line execute

```
mysql> source file_name
```

See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-batch-commands.html) for details.

Comment: Where is this executed? Where do the statements go? Please specify in code - would be really helpful

Comment: can you specify what database you are using? MySQL, sqlite, something else?